# How to replace one package with another using yum?

Tags: yum, rpm

I must be missing something obvious here. If there are two equally versioned RPM packages of the same software product, with one of them installed on one of my rigs (with a metric tonne of packages as dependencies), how can I replace it with another without going through the hassle of erasing and reinstalling an insane number of dependent packages?

I'd like to do it via `yum`. `rpm`-based solutions (with forcing) are grudgingly accepted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using YUM's shell transactions:

```
# yum shell
>
> remove <package>
> repo disable <repo ID of not required package>
> install <package>
> run
> exit
```

Comment: Brilliant! (extra characters added)

Comment: Also possible to do: `yum swap -- remove foo -- install bar` (not tested).

Comment: @DeerHunter, yum in CentOS 6 doesn't have 'swap' command. garethTheRed's answer works on CentOS 6 too