# how to swap yum repos from DVD to web

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

I have to migrate some systems from centos 8.0 to RHEL 8.7 so, I prepare it to run convert2rhel, and so, previously, I wish to upgrade to centos 8.5

The system was installed in 2019 in the beginning of centos 8 from a dvd (8.0.1905) and since, it has lived through a local mirror.

When I run `yum update` on the local 8.5 mirror, it seems to work, but a buch of dependancy packages from `localAppstream`  will be removed as "un-needed"

How can I tell yum to upgrade my packages from *localAppstream* using latests in *appstream* ?

I tried `yum swap` and even a yum transaction with `yum shell` as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158588/358922
with no luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

CentOS was free, and those repositories don't just migrate into RHEL.

For **RHEL** you would use the `subscription-manager` to register your system, based on a paid for redhat license.  In doing so, it will update your `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` file which is likely currently empty.  It will then gain a hundred or so entries many of which will be `enabled = 0` but the ones that are the base functionality which will be enabled when use have a paid for license are like this

```
[rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms]
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)
baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel8/$releasever/x86_64/baseos/os

[rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms]
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel8/$releasever/x86_64/appstream/os

[codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms]
name = Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)
baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel8/$releasever/x86_64/codeready-builder/os
```

- quick description to set up a local repository such as /root/repo/

  - copy rpm files into `/root/repo`
  - `createrepo /root/repo`
  - create `/etc/yum.repos.d/localrepo.repo` with contents similar to above but

    - change `baseurl` entry to `= file:///root/repo`
    - you can do this local repo from the contents of rhel-8.7-x86_64-dvd.iso

      - `mkdir /root/repo/rhel8.7; mkdir /root/repo/temp`
      - `mount -o loop rhel-8.7-x86_64-dvd.iso /root/repo/temp`
      - `cp -r /root/repo/temp  /root/repo/rhel8.7`
      - `umount /root/repo/temp; rmdir /root/repo/temp`
      - in `/etc/yum.repos.d/whatevername.repo` have `baseurl=file:///root/repo/rhel8.7`

and of course get the free EPEL (extra packages for enterprise linux)

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/

see `epel-release-latest-8` link on that page, getting `epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm` which will set up `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` for you.